# YouTube Data API V3 - automate authorisation process instead of manual intervention

Tags: java, oauth, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the YouTube Data API V3 to upload videos to my youtube channel. The authorisation code in the provided sample code needs manual intervention in authorisation process. Every time when I restart my server, it opens the browser and ask me for authentication and permissions. For my Windows PC, its fine, but I'm going to deploy this code to a remote Linux machine on which I only have SSH access.

Is there any way to make this process automatic? Like by accessing the API using normal credentials(username and password) or making this process one time (permanent authentication/authorisation).

I did read some threads on this topic which points to use refresh token.

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: @SusajSN Yes. To fix this, I did generate a credentials file using local server setup & moved that file over to my cloud server setup at root/user profile level from where my setup was referring it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally i would say you should use a service account then you wouldn't need to do the authentication process at all.   However the YouTube API doesn't support service account authentication.

I am at a lost to explain why your authentication would need to be refreshed after a reboot.  Your code should be saving the credentials file which contains a refresh token the refresh token should continue to work even after a reboot.  I will hazard to guess there is an issue with your code.

This is a [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/java) example which shows how the credentials are saved. Its for people api and not Youtube let me know if you need any help altering it for YouTube.   These credentials will not be deleted when the server is rebooted.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleService;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.PeopleScopes;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.ListConnectionsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.people.v1.model.Person;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Quickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "People API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/people.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/people.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(PeopleScopes.CONTACTS_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            Quickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized People client service.
     * @return an authorized People client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static PeopleService getPeopleService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new PeopleService.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        PeopleService service = getPeopleService();

        // Request 10 connections.
        ListConnectionsResponse response = service.people().connections()
                .list("people/me")
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setPersonFields("names,emailAddresses")
                .execute();

        // Print display name of connections if available.
        List<Person> connections = response.getConnections();
        if (connections != null && connections.size() > 0) {
            for (Person person : connections) {
                List<Name> names = person.getNames();
                if (names != null && names.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + person.getNames().get(0)
                            .getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No names available for connection.");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No connections found.");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer: As for your server issue and how to make this automatic. The answer is you cant. There is no way to authenticate with out a browser window.   You should authenticate on your windows pc copy the credentials file I spoke of over to your server.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me how can I use refresh token to avoid repeated authentication process?

Comment: The library should be handling that for you.  Its not requesting again is it?

Comment: Actually I did use the Auth class for authorisation , but after 1 hour or something its asking me to authorise again. is there any way to stop this. I tried your solution of copying the credentials file to the server, its working. But after one hour I have to repeat the process again.

Comment: access token only lasts for an hour then the refresh token will need to be used to get a new access token.   I cant tell you if that is possible with the ruby library sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.  That means every one hour I need to change the credentials file and upload it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

How are you storing your credentials? If your server shuts down, will your credentials be also lost with it? You could consider storing it in an external database or if it's a web app you can store it as a cookie.

Refresh tokens are only issued once (during the first initial authentication) so if you've already authorized your account before, you'll need to visit your app permissions and remove it. Then try authorizing again, and save that refresh token. If you properly save the refresh token (using cookies/database/whatever), then you'll be given a new access token upon request. Using this method, you won't have to reauthorize every time

Comment: Can you please explain this process step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late...

1) Create new project in [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

2) Create oauth 2.0 Cliend id. In application type select - Other.

3) Download json file, rename it to "client_secret.json" and add it to /resources folder (for Gradle project).

4) Create java file and add this code:

```
public class YoutubeAuth {

    private static final String CLIENT_SECRETS= "/client_secret.json";

    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES =
            Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");

    private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
            new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/youtube");

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Custom Application Name";

    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /**
     * Create an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static Credential authorize(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport) throws IOException {

       // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = YoutubeAuth.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENT_SECRETS);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                        .build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service.
     *
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        final NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

        dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);

        Credential credential = authorize(httpTransport);


        return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Pay attention to this lines of code:

```
private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),".store/youtube");
```

and to this method inside authorize() method:

```
.setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
```

and to this method inside getService() method:

```
dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);


YouTube youtubeService = LfkYoutubeAuth.getService();
...
// some other code
---
```

So you can use Youtube Service like this

Comment: *2) Create oauth 2.0 Cliend id. In application type select - Other.*

i can't see the `Other` option in there.

Comment: Maybe something has changed.  You can check between android and web application or something else.

Comment: And i wonder why we need this manual intervention to authorise. How to automate this.